# Speech Recognition All Dictionary - Close Form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I am trying to make speech recognition program like JARVIS but now im stacked. I want to make write mode . This mode writes everything whatever i say.

First of all, I thought i can use txt file for all library.I send my all txt dictionary to Array and I defined String Array as grammer file but i cant use it for sentence only for words.

While txt sent to Strings to array pc stacks. I cant explain myself but i want to use speech to text library and i want to use all grammers for it. When i say hello, how are you write it for me it can write it aswell. my codes

**Thats my IO. It's for all dictionary words.**

```
private ArrayList IoS(int x)
{

    ArrayList returner = new ArrayList();
    string path = "";
    string commandDict = @"../../documents/dictionary_C.txt";
    string fullDict = @"../../documents/dictionary_F.txt";
    if (x == 0)
        path = commandDict;
    else
        if (x == 1)
            path = fullDict;

    if (IoChecker(path) == false)
        Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR");

    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string checker = "";
        while ((checker = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            returner.Add(checker);
        }
    }
    return returner;

}
```

**My speech recognition grammer code.**

```
private void panel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ListC = 0;
    IO io = new IO();

    string[] list = new string[io.IoSCaller(ListC).Count];
    Choices sList = new Choices();
    for (int i = 0; i < io.IoSCaller(ListC).Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = (io.IoSCaller(ListC)[i].ToString());
    }

    sList.Add(list);
    Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));

    try
    {
        sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
        sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
        sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        sRecognize.Recognize();
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Its working for words but not working for sentence and I cant save all sentece. What can i do for it i want to use all dictionary and serial input not word by word.

My second Question
I want to close all program but I cannot close my program.
I am using this codes but non of them close my program. I cant close my program inside of my code please help me.

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
Environment.Exit(0);
Application.Exit();
```

---

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("vshost32");
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process proc in procs)
{
    proc.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

I'm new for C# coding. Thanks for everything.

Comment: For free form recognition it's better to use dictation mode without grammar. If you want word repeats with the grammar you need to use constructor with repeats http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd147124.aspx

Comment: Yeah i tried it but my dictionary library has too many words for it . I want to use all english library for it. and when i tried to add library from my text program stacks and I wait 2 min for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading a lot of strings into your grammar to make it recognize many words, you better use a [`DictationGrammar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx). This is a grammar that recognizes everything you say. So instead of building your grammar from a lot of strings, use `new DictationGrammar()` as parameter for the `LoadGrammar` method. Also, it's not necessary to call `Recognize()` after you call `RecognizeAsync()`.

```
sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
sRecognize.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

> My second Question I want to close all program but I cannot close my program.

For this, I need some extra information. Is it a Console Application, Windows Forms Application or WPF application?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your anwser. My application is Windows Form Application. In my program I use this code:
`private void exitTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            this.Close();
}`
It can close application but in other case
`case "exit":
case "close program":        
this.close();
break;`

doesnt work :(

Comment: @AyberkHalac Are you sure the `this.Close();` gets executed? You can use a debugger to find out what happens in the switch statement.